# Draw a object comparing two different values of stencil buffer

Tags: c++, opengl

First draw *Geometry_A* and write to stencil buffer with the following value.

```
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);  // replace stencil buffer values to ref=1
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 1, 0xFF); // never pass stencil test
glStencilMask(0xFF);
Draw Geometry_A
```

Draw *Geometry_B* and write to the stencil buffer with following Value.

```
 glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 2, 0xFF); // never pass stencil test
 glStencilMask(0xFF);
 Draw Geometry_B
```

Draw *Geomtery_C* Comparing the stencil value of *Geometry_A*

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
```

Draw *Geomtery_D* Comparing the stencil value of *Geometry_B*

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 2, 0xFF);
```

Can we draw a geometry comparing both the values of stencil buffer from *Geometry_A* and *Geometry_B*

something like.

```
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1 & 2, 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we draw a geometry comparing both the values of stencil buffer from *Geometry_A* and *Geometry_B*

Yes of course, just set a bit in the stencil buffer, instead of changing all bits.

Set the bit mask `0x01` for geometry *Geometry_A*

```
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 1, 0xFF); // never pass stencil test
glStencilMask(0x01);
```

Set the bit mask `0x02` for geometry *Geometry_B*

```
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 2, 0xFF); // never pass stencil test
glStencilMask(0x02);
```

If you want to find the sections where *Geometry_A* and *Geometry_B* have been drawn, then you have to find test if the fist 2 bits in the stencil buffer are set.

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 3, 0x03);
```

Note, with this approach the bits 3 to 8 are not affected at all.